# Using rCharts with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I am developing a Shiny application and I'm having trouble when integrating with rCharts. I made a simple app with a database "Cars93" that everyone can access to exemplify my problem.

I put a table and a graph in the app, the table is only to test if the data is correct.

My problem is that the graph does not appear.

Thanks in advance!

Luis

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(MASS)
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')
mydata<-Cars93

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('RCharts - Test'),
  sidebarPanel(

    selectInput("Manufacturer2", "Select a Manufacturer", levels(droplevels(mydata$Manufacturer)),
                          selected = "Acura"
    ),
    selectInput("Type2", "Select a Type", levels(droplevels(mydata$Type))[3:4],selected = levels(droplevels(mydata$Type))[3]
    ),




    width = 3

  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(

      tabPanel("Table",dataTableOutput('mytable')),
      tabPanel("Chart",showOutput('myplot', 'polycharts'))




    )
  ))
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(MASS)
options(RCHART_WIDTH = 800)
mydata<-Cars93
data2<-Cars93

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "Type2", choices = levels(droplevels(mydata$Type[mydata$Manufacturer %in% input$Manufacturer2])),selected = levels(droplevels(mydata$Type[mydata$Manufacturer %in% input$Manufacturer2]))[1]
    )
  })

  output$mytable = renderDataTable({
    MANUFACTURER = input$Manufacturer2
    TYPE = input$Type2
    mydata<- mydata[mydata$Manufacturer %in% MANUFACTURER  & mydata$Type %in% TYPE,]
    mydata<-mydata[,c("Manufacturer","Type","Model","Weight")]
    mydata
  })

  output$myplot<- renderChart({
    MANUFACTURER = input$Manufacturer2
    TYPE = input$Type2
    mydata<- mydata[mydata$Manufacturer %in% MANUFACTURER  & mydata$Type %in% TYPE,]
    p1<-rPlot(Weight ~ Model, color = 'Model', data = mydata, type = 'bar')

    p1$guides(
      color = list(
        numticks = length(factor(mydata$Model))
      ),
      y = list(
        min = 0,
        max = 10
      )
    )
    return(p1)
  })

})
```

Comment: You need to set the `dom`. `p1$set(dom = "myplot")` in `renderChart` or use `renderChart2` unstead of `renderChart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `renderChart` in your server function you need to set the `dom`:

```
p1$set(dom = "myplot")
```

where `dom` should take the same value that `output` is assigned from `renderChart`

Alternatively there is a handy `renderChart2` that can be used instead of `renderChart` and then the `dom` doesnt need to be set.

Comment: This app has another problem, I guess it is in the "observe" function. Depending on the user's choices for the Manufacturer or Type, the Type does not refresh and the plot does not appear.

Comment: Maybe start another question with an example of it not working